# How to convert month(int) into month name (string)

Tags: c, string, struct

I'm having a problem with a function i'm working on. I am able to get the proper data, just not print out the names of the month as well.

sample output i'm getting:

```
|   Month   | High  |  Low  |  Avg  | Precip  |
|-----------|-------|-------|-------|---------|
1    | 9.8 | -26.2 | -7.8 | 55.3    |
2    | 7.5 | -23.3 | -8.6 | 33.1    |
3    | 14.2 | -19.6 | -4.7 | 33.2   |
4    | 23.7 | -5.3 | 6.2 | 56.8 |
5    | 33.0 | -0.6 | 13.9 | 62.7    |
6    | 32.1 | 8.0 | 19.7 | 69.7 |
7    | 34.9 | 12.6 | 22.2 | 181.8   |
8    | 31.5 | 11.0 | 20.9 | 69.2    |
9    | 34.1 | 5.0 | 16.1 | 69.0 |
10    | 24.8 | -2.9 | 10.8 | 56.9   |
11    | 16.0 | -12.8 | 2.1 | 36.2   |
12    | 15.6 | -17.8 | -4.2 | 65.8
```

I want to conver digits 1-12 to there proper month names. Ie: 1 = January.

```
void printMonthlyStatistic(int month,const struct MonthlyStatistic* monthly)
```

is what the function looks like

```
for(i=0;i<12;i++){
   printMonthlyStatistic(i+1,&monthly[i])
```

and is called in main as such.

Any help onto where to look for the proper method to complete this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Use the number as an index into an array.

Comment: `switch (month)`? Or better yet, have an array of month name strings where the index is the month int value.

Comment: This is what `strftime()` is for.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an array to store the name of the month, like:

```
const char * months[12] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
```

You can get the name of the month easily, for example, if `index = 1`, then

```
months[index -1]
```

will give you the first month name: *January*.

---

The following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
    printf("%s ", months[i]);
}
```

will output:

> January February March April May June July August September October
>   November December

Comment: const char * months[12] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May",     "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    int i = 0;

    printf("  %s    | %.1f | %.1f | %.1f | %.1f     |\n", months[i],
    monthly->maxTemperature,
    monthly->minTemperature, monthly->averageTemperature,
    monthly->totalPrecipitation);

    }

Comment: that will just display January on every line. what i'm trying to figure out is how to display each individual month with the proper data

Comment: As you initialized `i = 0` that's why you get **January** always. Please read the edited answer.

Comment: @johnnysparks13 After first statement you have initialized `i=0` , and at index 0 in array you have saved **January** . value of `i` is not updating so you are getting same answer everytime

Comment: Perhaps make `months[]` `const` also: `const char * const months[12] = ....`.  It depend on OP's needs, but this way may be more optimize-able.

Answer (score -4):

You can maintain Month Array of String like
**char months_names[12] = {Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec};**

You can Just paas integer number month to array for getting String value

months_names["Integrer Value"] You will get String name of month.

Comment: The array type seems to be wrong - should be `const char *`, the array values need to be strings and need to -1 for the index as OP says Jan is 1.

Comment: Thats not a proper array. a) you haven't initialised it right, b) it should be char * months_names[12] and not just what you wrote.