# Trying to create a function to determine the month name from a number

Tags: c, function, struct

I've got an assignment that needs me to print some sort of item names in the grocery store, it's still in my works, but I'm a bit lost on creating the function to read month number and display month name

Here I must use the struct, so I want the function to read the month number from the struct that already got a value later from the user I want them display the month name

the function is on the bottom part of the code, and the line which I wanted to print the function is on the bottom of case 1 in int main

Any help please? I'm still a complete beginner, I'm sorry if my language is bad

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Meats
{
  char meat_type[2];
  char DOP[15];
  int month;
  int year;

} meatdata;

struct Produce
{
  char type[3];
  char date_received[15];
} producedata;

struct Dairy
{
  int month;
  char year[5];
} dairydata;

struct Canned_goods
{
  int month;
  char year[5];
  int aisle_num;
  char aisle_side[2];
} canneddata;

struct nonfoods
{
  char category[3];
  int aisle_num;
  char aisle_side[2];
} nonfoodsdata;

int month_calculation(int monno);

int
main ()
{
  char item_name[22];
  int pilihan;
  int cost;
  
  printf("Enter your item name: ");
  scanf("%s", item_name);
  printf("Item cost? ");
  scanf("%d", &cost);
  
  printf("(M)eat,(P)roduce,(D)airy,(C)anned Goods,(N)onFoods\n\n");
 
         printf ("\nChoose your product type\n");
         printf ("1. Meat\n");
         printf ("2. Produce\n");
         printf ("3. Dairy\n");
         printf ("4. Canned goods\n");
         printf ("5. Nonfoods");
         printf ("\n\nYour Choice? : ");
         scanf ("%d", &pilihan);
         
         switch (pilihan)
         {
             case 1:
             printf("Red Meat || Poultry || Fish\n");
             printf("\nInput the meat type (R/P/F): ");
             scanf("%s", meatdata.meat_type);
             getchar();
             
             printf("\n\nInput Date of Production (Day Month Year): ");
             scanf ("%[^\n]", meatdata.DOP);
             
             printf("\n\nInput the month of expiration: ");
             scanf ("%d", &meatdata.month);
             
               printf("\n\nInput the month of expiration: ");
             scanf ("%d", &meatdata.year);
             
             printf ("\n %s %dM %s %s %d %d", item_name, cost, meatdata.meat_type, meatdata.DOP, meatdata.month, meatdata.year);
             
             printf ("\nThe %s Costs %d. Its an %s type of meat made at %s and will expire in %s %d", item_name, cost, meatdata.meat_type, meatdata.DOP, month_calculation(meatdata.month), meatdata.year);
             
             
             
             break;
             
             case 2:
             
             break;
             
             case 3:
             
             break;
             
             case 4:
             
             break;
             
             case 5:

             exit(0);
             
         }
     
     
     return 0;





}

int month_calculation(int monno)
{
   
   switch(monno)
   {
    case 1:
           printf("January\n");
           break;
    case 2:
           printf("February\n");
           break;
    case 3:
           printf("March\n");
           break;
    case 4:
           printf("April\n");
           break;
    case 5:
           printf("May\n");
           break;
    case 6:
           printf("June\n");
           break;
    case 7:
           printf("July\n");
           break;
    case 8:
           printf("August\n");
           break;
    case 9:
           printf("September\n");
           break;
    case 10:
           printf("October\n");
           break;
    case 11:
           printf("November\n");
           break;
    case 12:
           printf("December\n");
           break;
      }
}
```

I already tried putting it in int main, but it'll be too long, and I can't seem to use it again properly, I don't know why. I tried to copy the more proper code from the internet to find the month name, but I'm still having a hard time trying to make it a function and use the function.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! I was reviewing your question and for future reference I think you'll help yourself and others answer better and faster by using variable names in your question. Ex. You referred to a struct as "the struct". You have multiple structs in your code. To help others assist you better please consider clarifying variables by their name and not just data type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert month(int) into month name (string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080583/how-to-convert-monthint-into-month-name-string)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple. You want a function that takes an integer (expects 1<=x<=12) and returns a **pointer** to a constant string that can be used by the calling function.

```
const char *month_as_string( int monno ) { // NB: Name changed!
    const char *monNames[] = {
        "xxx", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
    };

    return (1 <= monno && monno <= 12) ? monNames[ monno ] : "Bad month number";
}
```

This will work in most English speaking situations.

I recommend using the three-letter version of the name for brevity...

Notice that "xxx" has been used to occupy element #0 of the array. These 4 bytes of data are insignificant and obviate the need to subtract 1 from the month value...

**UPDATE**
Of course, if you like cryptic, minimalist and branchless code, you could use this:

```
const char *month_as_string( unsigned int no ) {
    return  "BAD\0"
            "Jan\0Feb\0Mar\0Apr\0May\0Jun\0"
            "Jul\0Aug\0Sep\0Oct\0Nov\0Dec"
            + ( 1<=no && no<=12 ) * no * 4;
}
```

This is a **tested**, single purpose function (ie: not subject to modification or elaboration to meet changing requirements.) This is not the way to write code that may be extended or revised some time in the future.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much, it works well and now I can continue my work!